# how to properly record details of big purchase into the ledger?

Tags: accounting, double-entry

Suppose I bought the car for $10k. I would imagine that journal entry for the purchase would include $10k on debit and credit side and go to accounts like 'Payable' and 'Assets'.

Suppose I need to record make, year and other facts about the car for reporting purposes.

How such record is called and where does it go? Does it go to some auxiliary database which is not part of double entry accounting system? Or there is well-known way to keep such information inside of usual account framework?

Comment: It’s a Purchase of Equipment journal entry.  (That seems too obvious, but it’s the start.)

Comment: This is more an Accounting question than a Personal Finance question, which I'm afraid puts it out of scope here.

Comment: @RonJohn make sense, but where equipment description goes? and what form? Is any accepted way to save complete machine-readable description? I've seen descriptions like text with some typos and generally useful for the person who wrote that only.

Comment: @keshlam if you have the link to better SO location - feel free to post that here

Comment: There's no accounting SO site, but it's off topic here

Comment: "complete machine readable description" will depend on what software you're using. Read the fine manual, or ask their support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you buy a car for $10,000 cash, you post a $10,000 credit to cash (an asset) and a $10,000 debit to some relevant expense account. Or if want to keep track of the value of the car, you post $10,000 credit to cash and $10,000 debit to "automobile assets" or whatever account you want to put that under. As the car depreciates you would post credits to the automobile asset account and debits to depreciation expense.

If you borrow money to buy the car, you post the down payment as a credit to cash and the amount financed as a credit to "auto loan" or some other liability account. Then post a debit for the value of the car as above. As you pay off the loan, you credit cash and debit auto loan.

As to where you post make and model and year and such, that depends on your accounting system. If it's a computer system and there are fields where you could enter such info, you could put it in there. I doubt an accounting system would have fields specifically for the sort of information you'd have about a car, like make and model, but they might have general fields for "notes" or "additional info" or such. Otherwise, just record this somewhere else. If you're buying a personal car, you probably just have one or two, so you could just type this info into a Word file. If you have a fleet of cars, you probably want a separate database for that. If you're in a business that involves managing a fleet of cars, like a car rental company or an auto dealership, you might have accounting software specific to your industry that would have relevant fields in the database. But from the fact that you're asking this question, I'd guess probably not.

Comment: thanks for comprehensive answer, it helps me a lot. I was looking for some general about how ledger and additional non-financial data could be related. So the answer gives me enough clues on that.